# Gitlab CI pipeline pull fails without trace

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

After updating Docker (to newest 19.03.13) and postgres (from 12 to 13) my gitlab pipeline now fails - without an traces. It is triggered but pull fails after 1second, without any traces.

Gitlab runner is running, and is not shared with other projects.
Docker is connected to registry and can build and push updated images.
Have tried to clone to new repo and redo gitlab runner registration. Haven't found any other similar issues posted here. Have run out of ideas of what to try.

Any help will be much appreciated !

[The pipeline output (ie no output)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeJWE.png)

**My .gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - pull
  - build
  - lint
  - push
  - cleanup
  - deploy

before_script:
  - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_BUILD_TOKEN" "$CI_REGISTRY"

pull:
  stage: pull
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - docker pull "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build --tag="$CI_PIPELINE_ID":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" --cache-from="$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest .

lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - docker-compose -p "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" -f docker-compose.ci.yml run app ls
    - docker-compose -p "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" -f docker-compose.ci.yml run app cat tox.ini
    - export CI_PIPELINE_ID=$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - export CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - docker-compose -p "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" -f docker-compose.ci.yml run app flake8 .

push image:
  stage: push
  only:
    - master
    - tags
  script:
    - docker tag "$CI_PIPELINE_ID":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"

push latest:
  stage: push
  script:
    - docker tag "$CI_PIPELINE_ID":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE":latest

cleanup:
  stage: cleanup
  when: always
  script:
    - docker rmi -f "$CI_PIPELINE_ID":"$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    - docker-compose -p "$CI_PIPELINE_ID" -f docker-compose.ci.yml down --remove-orphans

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
    - tags
  script:
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.deploy.yml pull
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.deploy.yml down --remove-orphans
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.deploy.yml up -d
```

**My docker-compose.ci.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: "${CI_PIPELINE_ID}:${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}"
```

**My docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my_account/my_project:latest
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
      - "4777:22"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    command: "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"

    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres:
  static-files:
  media-files:
```

**My docker-compose.deploy.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my_account/my_project:latest
    command: "sh /scripts/run.sh"
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - media-files:/media-files
      - static-files:/static-files
      - frontend:/frontend-build

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    env_file:
      - dev.env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - static-files:/static-files/
      - media-files:/media-files/
      - frontend:/frontend

volumes:
  postgres:
  static-files:
  media-files:
  frontend:
```

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda:latest

ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -qqy \
    wget \
    bzip2 \
    graphviz \
    libssl-dev \
    openssh-server

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i '/PermitRootLogin/c\PermitRootLogin yes' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

RUN mkdir -p /backend
COPY ./backend/requirements.yml /backend/requirements.yml
RUN /opt/conda/bin/conda env create -f /backend/requirements.yml
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/backend/bin:$PATH

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
RUN echo "source activate backend" >~/.bashrc

COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN chmod +x ./scripts*

COPY ./backend /backend
COPY ./frontend /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend

RUN npm install && npm run build

WORKDIR /backend
```

Comment: what do the runner logs say in debug mode?